# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/com.headway/save] in DispatcherServlet with name 'headway'

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>headway</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>headway</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/save</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

headway-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    

<context:component-scan base-package="com.headway"></context:component-scan>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>  
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
</bean>  
  </beans>
```

empform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Add New Employee</h1>  
       <form method="post" action="save">    
        <table >    
         <tr>    
          <td>Name : </td>   
          <td><input path="name"  /></td>  
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
          <td>Salary :</td>    
          <td><input path="salary" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td>Designation :</td>    
          <td><input path="designation" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td> </td>    
          <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>    
         </tr>    
        </table>    
       <form>    
</body>
</html>
```

viewform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employees List</h1>  
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th><th>Designation</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
   <tr>  
   <td>${emp.id}</td>  
   <td>${emp.name}</td>  
   <td>${emp.salary}</td>  
   <td>${emp.designation}</td>  
   <td><a href="editemp/${emp.id}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.id}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
   <br/>  
   <a href="empform">Add New Employee</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Emp.java

```
package com.javatpoint.beans;

public class Emp {  
private int id;  
private String name;  
private float salary;  
private String designation;  

public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getName() {  
    return name;  
}  
public void setName(String name) {  
    this.name = name;  
}  
public float getSalary() {  
    return salary;  
}  
public void setSalary(float salary) {  
    this.salary = salary;  
}  
public String getDesignation() {  
    return designation;  
}  
public void setDesignation(String designation) {  
    this.designation = designation;  
}  

}
```

EmpController.java

```
package com.javatpoint.controllers;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
import com.javatpoint.beans.Emp;  
import com.javatpoint.dao.EmpDao;  
@Controller  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;//will inject dao from xml file  

    /*It displays a form to input data, here "command" is a reserved request attribute 
     *which is used to display object data into form 
     */  
    @RequestMapping("/empform")  
    public ModelAndView showform(){  
        return new ModelAndView("empform","command",new Emp());  
    }  
    /*It saves object into database. The @ModelAttribute puts request data 
     *  into model object. You need to mention RequestMethod.POST method  
     *  because default request is GET*/  
    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Emp emp){  
        dao.save(emp);  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp.jsp");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
    }  
    /* It provides list of employees in model object */  
    @RequestMapping("/viewemp")  
    public ModelAndView viewemp(){  
        List<Emp> list=dao.getEmployees();  
        return new ModelAndView("viewemp","list",list);  
    }  

}
```

EmpDao.java

```
package com.javatpoint.dao;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  
import java.util.List;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;  
import com.javatpoint.beans.Emp;  

public class EmpDao {  
JdbcTemplate template;  
private static final String driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/headway";

private static final String dbUsername = "root";

private static final String dbPassword = "toor";
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  
public int save(Emp p){  
    String sql="insert into Emp99(name,salary,designation)  values('"+p.getName()+"',"+p.getSalary()+",'"+p.getDesignation()+"')";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public int update(Emp p){  
    String sql="update Emp99 set name='"+p.getName()+"', salary="+p.getSalary()+", designation='"+p.getDesignation()+"' where id="+p.getId()+"";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public int delete(int id){  
    String sql="delete from Emp99 where id="+id+"";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public Emp getEmpById(int id){  
    String sql="select * from Emp99 where id=?";  
    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Emp>(Emp.class));  
}  
public List<Emp> getEmployees(){  
    return template.query("select * from Emp99",new RowMapper<Emp>(){  
        public Emp mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {  
            Emp e=new Emp();  
            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
            e.setName(rs.getString(2));  
            e.setSalary(rs.getFloat(3));  
            e.setDesignation(rs.getString(4));  
            return e;  
        }  
    });  
}  
}
```

hii

I am trying to insert the data in to database by using the spring mvc.
 while execution it shows the  HTTP Status 404 -  error and server console shows the --"No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/com.headway/save] in DispatcherServlet with name 'headway'".

please provide the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do two things

a. In `web.xml`,change url-pattern from `/save` to `/`

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>headway</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

b. In `headway-servlet.xml` change `base-package` from `com.headway` to `com.javatpoint`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"/>
```